# How to Add a Dynamic Layer to an Esri Map Control Programatically in WPF?

Tags: wpf, dictionary, gis, esri

Just as the question asks.

I have an Esri map control and want to add a Rastor image to the control in WPF and don't know how to do it.  I see that I can add layers to the Map control, but is there a way to add a Raster image to a map control?

I did find this code to turn the raster image into a Dynamic layer, but Im still lost on how to add a dynamic layer to the control it self.

http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/silverlight/index.cfm?fa=codeGalleryDetails&scriptID=16723

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to just add an image (say bmp file) to the map? If yes, then its really easy by creating a graphic and adding it to a graphic layer on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to modify that code I found at the gallery.  Its still nothing close to how I would like it, but its a definite start.